# Why i can't use switch-case with chars?

Tags: c, char, switch-statement, case, scanf

I can't use chars in switch-cases.

```
printf("choose: \n[w=woman] [m=man] ");
scanf_s("%s" ,&c); 

switch (c) {
    case 'w':
        printf("45,5"); break;
    case 'm':
        printf("50"); break;

}
```

When we type "w" the code suppose to write "45,5" on the screen but the code doesn't do what we want. It works when i use the same code with necessary edits for numbers (int).

Comment: `%s` tries to read in a string, not a character.

Comment: What is `c`? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Is `c` (e.g.) `char c;` or `char c[10];`??? If the latter, try `switch (c[0])`. If it's a single char, you want: `scanf_s(" %c",&c);` Crank up the warnings with `-Wall`

Comment: The `scanf` functions are not intended to parse arbitrary user input.

Answer (score 1):

If the variable `c` has the type `char` then in the call of `scanf_s` you have to use the conversion specifier `%c` instead of `%s`

```
scanf_s( " %c", &c, ( rsize_t )1 );
```

Instead of `scanf_s` to input a character you could use function `scanf` like

```
scanf( " %c", &c );
```

In the both cases pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters as for example the new line character `'\n'` that can be stored in the input buffer after pressing the Enter key.

Comment: `scanf_s` is not portable: the C Standard mandates `(rsize_t)1` as posted in the answer, but the Microsoft compiler the OP is probably using has a different API and mandates `(UNSIGNED)1` for the size argument. Better use `scanf` and disable the warning with `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`

Comment: @chqrlie: `scanf_s` not "not portable", it's another example of [Microsoft screwing up when it comes to working with standards](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm#impementations). It's *Microsoft's implementation being non-conforming*. Again...

Comment: @DevSolar: of course it is a major screwup. Microsoft insisted on their *solution* to some of the C library shortcomings but never updated their inconsistent APIs after the `_s` functions made their way into Annex K. Their compiler obnoxiously insists on deprecating many standard functions, promoting the `_s` alternatives, which if used on their platforms make the code non portable because of these API inconsistencies and the lack of availability on other platforms. In this sense, code using `scanf_s` can be considered non portable, and using `scanf` properly is what I recommend.

Comment: @chqrlie I tend to *discourage* using `scanf` altogether in favor of `fgets` and subsequent application of `strtol`, `strtod` et al. -- less ways to shoot yourself in the foot without realizing.

Comment: @DevSolar: I agree, `scanf()` and `fscanf()` are poor tools for error recovery. A combination of `fgets()` or `getline()` and `sscanf()` or other parsing methods is much more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not the best solution for your problem, but i would recommend to look up,

> int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);

It is a standard function, to compare two strings, in case you would use multiple characters to match.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).